# What is going on in the background when you create a List<T>?

Tags: java

`List<T>` is an interface and can not normally be instantiated, however you can  create `List` of a fixed length through little hacks like `Arrays.asList`. Methods which return `List<T>` also seem to instantiate a `List`.

Given that `List` is an interface, what exactly does the JVM do to create it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interface can't be instantiated. If you see the code behind asList method its using arrayList. Its like:

```
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings("varargs")
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

However if you want to take advantage of runtime polymorphism, you could do something like:

```
List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
```

See that i used interface on left hand side and i can use either array backed array list implementation or a linked list based on my business scenario given advantage of one over the other.

Comment: What then is going on in `public <T> List<T> query(String sql, RowMapper<T> rowMapper)` in `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate`?

Comment: You could read the code [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.1.3.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#JdbcTemplate)

Comment: Yes, and there is nowhere any reference to creating a subtype of `List`; it seems to just add elements to a list. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Spring might be using reflection to get that result. You can dig deeper in the source code for that.

Comment: Alot of people seem to misunderstand me here - I know that you can't instantiate an interface, and I was moreso concerned about how Spring manages to return a `List` in its jdbc method and I used `Arrays.asList` as an example of this case. But I didn't know that `Arrays.asList` actually secretly return an `ArrayList`, so kudos to that!